# Get RGB-colors of a filled rectangle in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In my WPF project i have a `rectangle`. The `fill`-Color of the `rectangle` changes during runtime.

If the user clicks on the `rectangle`, he should get `rgb-values` of that `rectangle`.

I know that i can save it as `Brush` like this:

```
Brush brush = rectangle.Fill;
```

But i don't know how to get the `RGB`-values out of that?

what i would need is someting like:

```
labelRed.Text = brush.red;    
labelGreen.Text = brush.green;    
labelBlue.Text = brush.blue;
```

Comment: You can use [Fill](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Shapes_Shape_Fill) property of rectangle, to get brush from it

Comment: `var color = ((SolidColorBrush)rectangle.Fill).Color;`

Comment: In case it isn't totally obvious. The color struct has properties R, G and B https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.r?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `SolidColorBrush` from the [`Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Shapes.Shape.Fill);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) property, then get the Color struct from the `SolidColorBrush`, now the Color object, has the [`R`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.r?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Color.R);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) [`G`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.g?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Color.G);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) and [`B`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color.b?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Color.B);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) property

```
SolidColorBrush solidColorBrush = rectangle.Fill as SolidColorBrush;

if (solidColorBrush != null)
{
    Color color = solidColorBrush.Color;
    byte r = color.R;
    byte g = color.G;
    byte b = color.B;

    MessageBox.Show($"R{r}\nG{g}\nB{b}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that did it and is very good to understand!

Comment: Modified the code to show how to avoid an InvalidCastException in the potential case that `rectangle.Fill` is not a SolidColorBrush. This may happen when it's not assigned at all, or when it contains a different Brush type, e.g. an ImageBrush.